# Droppable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get draggable and droppable working and the drop part of this is not working.

```
$(function(){
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $("#dashboard").droppable({
        drop: function(){
            alert("HEY!");
        }
    });
});
```

Where am I making the mistake?

HTML-

```
<div class="leftSide">
    LeftSide
    <div id="favouritesDashboard" class="dashboard dashBoardIn">
         Dashboard
    </div>
</div>
<div class="center">
   Center
   <div class="draggable">
      DraggableTest
   </div>
```

This could also be an issue with version compatibility-

```
   <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

OTHER CODE THAT IS THERE-

```
$(dashboard).click(function(){
    console.log("HELLO");
    if($(dashboard).hasClass("dashBoardIn")){
        $(dashboard).removeClass("dashBoardIn");
    $(dashboard).addClass("dashBoardOut");
    $(".dashboard").stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-2px'},200);
} else{
    if($(dashboard).hasClass("dashBoardOut")){
        $(dashboard).removeClass("dashBoardOut");
        $(dashboard).addClass("dashBoardIn");
    $(".dashboard").stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-85px'},200);
    }
}
});
```

ANSWER-

Ok, so turns out I needed to add in an "accept" - like this

```
    $("#favouritesDashboard").droppable({
    accept:".draggable",
    drop: function() {
        console.log("HEY!");
    }
});
```

Comment: the alert("Hey") doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

You're using id instead of class - change that:

```
$("#dashboard").droppable({
```

to that (or use #favouritesDashboard id instead of just #dashboard):

```
$(".dashboard").droppable({
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/ovamaf/1/

If it still doesn't work it has to be something wrong with your setup (for example you didn't embed jquery or jquery ui correctly. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Check the link and compare to what you have - it's the simplest way here.

Comment: I checked that, it's the same- I've posted other code up- could this interfere with the droppable code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no id `#dashboard` and I assume `#favouritesDashboard` should be droppable

I think it should be,

```
$(function(){
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $("#favouritesDashboard").droppable({
        drop: function(){
            alert("HEY!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so, the Dashboard, is something that slides out - I've posted that code- could that code interfere with the droppable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I needed to add an accept-

```
$("#favouritesDashboard").droppable({
    accept:".draggable",
    drop: function() {
        console.log("HEY!");
    }
});
```

That works.